# C#: add data to dictionary from datafile

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to make import a data file and store all the values in the file in a dictionary.

The data looks like this:

```
1,101,2.5
4,103,3.0
1,103,3.0
1,104,3.5
```

I want to store the first(=key) and the last value(=value) in a dictionary. I have loaded the datafile and made a dictionary called: userPreferences.

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"datafile.data");
Dictionary<int, int> userPreferences = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

Now I want to make a loop that gets all the rows in the datafile and adds them to the dictionary.

```
foreach(?)
{
   string[] columns = line.Split(','); 
   userPreferences.Add(int.Parse(columns[0]), int.Parse(columns[1]));
}
```

I dont know where my foreach needs to loop through. I thought about something like this: `foreach(DataRow row in file.Tables[0].Rows)`

My question is how can I get all the data from the file in a dictionary?

Comment: `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename))`?

Comment: How do you expect to store a floating point number (the last value) in a dictionary whose types are `int`? Also a dictionary by definition means that the keys are **UNIQUE**. In your file example you have multiple keys (the first element) equal to `1` which of course is not possible. When you attempt to add an element to the dictionary with a key that already exists it will bomb out. So before going any further with this you should probably do some more research on the basic data types available in .NET (such as a dictionary structure) and clarify your requirements a bit more.

Comment: In addition to what @Darin says, you might be better off reading the data into a `List<Tuple<int, int, decimal>>` (or your own class), but that's not the scope of this question.